# Need help checking my solution for this geometry problem involving secant-secant angles

Tags: geometry

[image]

There are 4 secants forming the shape illustrated in the photo, dividing the circle into four arcs; arc K, N, H, and M in clockwise order. The problem is about solving for the unknown angle marked by the purple question mark.

Sorry for the horrible paint drawing. In any case, here's my solution:

[s.1]
$$50^\circ = \frac{1}{2} (K-H) \Rightarrow K - H=100^\circ $$ 
[s.2]
$$ 34^\circ = \frac{1}{2}(N-M) \Rightarrow N-M=68^\circ $$
since it's a circle:
$$(K+N)+(M+H)=360^\circ$$
adding [s.1] and [s.2];
$$(K+N)-(M+H)=168^\circ$$

solving this system, we get
$$2(M+H)= 360^\circ-168^\circ = 192^\circ \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}(M+H) = 48^\circ$$

therefore, $48^\circ$ is the answer. However, in our lesson the teacher said the answer was $45.5^\circ$. What's the correct answer then?

Comment: looks correct to me, maybe she made a mistake

Comment: You say it's your solution, but you don't say what problem you are solving. I take it, however, that you are trying to find the angle where there's a question mark. Better if you wrote this explicitly. Also, there's a $K$ in your equations, but no indication anywhere of what $K$ stands for.

Comment: They're all labeled in the photo, maybe you couldn't see it because it does have a light color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you made some mistake while writing down the values of angles. If you use 39° in place of 34° you will get 45.5° as the answer ,  following the same procedure as you did for 34°.

Comment: probably. ill have to check it with my teacher tomorrow first.

Comment: turns out she's the one who got it wrong, lol.